# Access JSF2 Managed Bean from RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have an application scoped managed bean which contains a list read from the database. Whenever another application makes changes to the database, it should trigger the web service to update the list in the managed bean.

I've tried

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ApplicationBean application= (ApplicationBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{applicationBean}", ApplicationBean.class);
```

The context variable was null, probably because the web service isn't called in the JSF context.

The REST resource class looks something like this:

```
@Path("/application")
public class ApplicationResource {

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public void updateIdCache(@PathParam("id") String internalid) {
    ApplicationBean application = ???;
    application.update(id);
    return;
}

}
```

The application server in use is tomcat 6. How is it done correctly?

Thanks & best regards

Comment: Can you use CDI from your application server?

Comment: @perissf Well, it's just a tomcat, not a full Java EE appserver, but the JSF2 and JAX-WS annotations do work.

Comment: Tomcat also now has a Java EE distro from Apache called [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org).  Includes JSF and CDI and is certified like JBoss or GlassFish.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think what you want is possible with JSF managed beans.

CDI beans have this functionality though.

JAX-WS with CDI:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jitu/archive/2010/02/19/jax-ws-cdi-java-ee-6-0

CDI implementation weld is commonly used:
Getting started with weld (covers tomcat 6)
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/gettingstarted.html

btw I love to work with CDI and I only use tomcat 6/7

Comment: So, what you're suggesting is to put the list with the data into a CDI bean instead? Then rewriting the JSF stuff to get the data from the CDI bean instead of the JSF managed bean would be required, which should be possible, correct?